# I am getting an error 'string object is not callable'

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginner in python..I am learning decorators and all that stuff..
This is my code

```
def addone(myfunc):
    def addsand():            
        return (str(myfunc())+'sand')
    return addsand()    



@addone
def oldfunc():
    return 'ham'

print oldfunc()
```

Answer (score 0):

The decorator should return a function, not a function's result. Replace `return addsand()` with `return addsand`.